# jquery is checked on radio button

Tags: jquery, if-statement, radio-button, checked

So, I have 3 radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="enabled" class="radio" <?php if($news_row['status']==1) echo 'checked'; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="status" value="disabled" class="radio" <?php if($news_row['status']==2) echo 'checked'; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="status" value="timer" class="radio" <?php if($news_row['status']==3) echo 'checked'; ?> />
```

And I'm trying to check if radio button with value timer is checked like so

```
if($('.radio [value=timer]').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('timer');
}
```

But obviously I'm doing something wrong since that code above doesn't work. So, which is the right way to do it? Using `.change()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m4m57/5/

Issue was the `space` here `f ($('.radio [value=timer]').is(':checked')) {`

```
                                    ^-----------
```

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    if ($('.radio[value=timer]').is(':checked')) {
        alert('say what');
        console.log('timer');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove **space**:

```
if($('.radio[value=timer]').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('timer');
}
```

You had space in `.radio [value=timer]` which means a different selector eg it meant `select all elements with value attribute set inside an element with class radio at any nested level`

Removing the space means `select all elements with class radio AND value attribute set`